# How can i send fourth image to next line?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website, in the gallery section i want to send fourth image to new line.

html:

```
<div class="gallery-images">
<div class="box">
    <img src="./images/gallery-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-first">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="./images/gallery-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-sec">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="./images/gallery-3.jpg" alt="" class="img-third">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="./images/gallery-4.jpg" alt="" class="img-fourth">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="./images/gallery-5.jpg" alt="" class="img-fifth">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <img src="./images/gallery-6.jpg" alt="" class="img-sixth">
</div>
```

css:
.gallery-images{

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column
  gap: 1em;
  margin: 10px;
  width:500px
```

}

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grid:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
</div>
```